# Retain quality when exporting jpeg (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

Hello I was trying to export in illustrator the same file in jpeg 100 and png formats but I noticed that the jpeg one is much worse than the png

illustrator @40 width scale: jpeg 100[image: jpeg 100]  */VS/* png[image: png]

Then I tried saving the png with MS Paint as jpeg

MS Paint: jpeg from illustrator's png [image: jpeg ms paint]

(MS Paint jpeg from illustrator's png is much better quality than the main jpeg directly from illustrator)

**The question is**... Is there a way to fix the quality drop when exporting as jpeg directly in illustrator? or I have to do this process of saving with paint for everything?

By the way, this is the 1x raster png version of the picture
https://s9.postimg.cc/vftmrlb6n/Vector_Improvements_1x.png

Comment: With Illustrator it can be best to reduce the vector art, then export rather than resizing *while* exporting in the same step.

Comment: there's a ton of detail in the original image, you might want to do a separate version with less details before reducing the size so much.

Comment: @Luciano I was thinking to save it again as jpg after the png in post but I was wondering if there's a direct way to fix it... and surprisingly it was simple enough (the answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Export for Screens Dialog" `File > Export > Export for screens`, there are options for the respective formats which you can try to adjust:

[image: Export For Screens]
[image: Format options]

Comment: Thanks! this fixed it...
I changed AA to supersampling (which I guess is better for art) instead of hinted (which is for text)...

Comment: the difference is dramatic in the case of my logo